# how to add roman numbers in ms word 2013

Tags: ms-word

I need add roman numbers in ms word 2013. I do not need add page numbers I only need change My numbers in the contents to roman numbers.

like this way

```
ABSTRACT……………………………………………………………………………….…. ii

ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS……………………………………………………………........... vi

TABLE OF CONTENTS……………………………………………………………………... vi

LIST OF FIGURES…………………………………………………………………………… vi
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

From Home ribbon in Paragraph Group Click Multilevel Text. Then select Define New Multilevel List [Multilevel Text Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHlMY.png). Then choose Number Style for this level.  [Number Style for this level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAZn4.png).

Comment: @Fernando Try this [https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/09/10/create-table-of-contents-word/ ]